# CSS - Hover an image to make a separate div fade in

Tags: html, css

I have a site here: https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk- if you scroll down to the LATEST NEWS FROM THE ACADEMY section you will see two featured blog posts. I have a nice hover state where the image grows.

But as well as the image growing, on hover of the image, I would like a subtitle (in a separate div) to fade in and become visible. It's currently `opacity: 0;` and I would like to to transition into `opacity: l;` I have this following code but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
.feat-sub-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgba(248, 79, 84, 0.8);
    padding: 15px 15px 5px 25px;
    opacity: 0;
}


.feat-image img:hover +.feat-sub-title {
    opacity: 1;
}

.feat-image img {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.feat-image img:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.06);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.06);
    transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

Here's the PHP loop thats outputting the two posts:

```
<?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="feat-post">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="feat-title">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="feat-sub-title">
                    <h4><?php the_field('subtitle'); ?></h4>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="feat-image">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>



      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="feat-post">

        <a href="https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/what-is-seo-getting-ranked-on-the-only-page-that-matters/">
            <div class="feat-title">
                <h3>What is SEO?</h3>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/what-is-seo-getting-ranked-on-the-only-page-that-matters/">
            <div class="feat-sub-title">
                <h4>Getting Ranked on The Only Page That Matters!</h4>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/what-is-seo-getting-ranked-on-the-only-page-that-matters/">
            <div class="feat-image">
                <img width="1920" height="1271" src="https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/What-is-SEO-banner.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="What is SEO?" srcset="https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/What-is-SEO-banner.jpg 1920w, https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/What-is-SEO-banner-300x199.jpg 300w, https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/What-is-SEO-banner-768x508.jpg 768w, https://seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/What-is-SEO-banner-1024x678.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px">               </div>
        </a>

    </div>
```

With the code you have you can do it this way:

```
.feat-post:hover .feat-sub-title {
      opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a great solution, I didn't thing of putting the hover on the container! :) Thanks.